# Spring interceptor works with xml but not with config class

Tags: java, xml, spring, annotations, interceptor

Im currently using an interceptor configured with xml like this :

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.resthub.dashboard.BasicInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

But I would like to put this in my config class :

```
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan("org.resthub.dashboard")
    @EnableWebMvc
    @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
    public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

        @Override
        public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
            registry.addInterceptor(new BasicInterceptor());
        }

        @Bean
        public InternalResourceViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
            InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
            resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            return resolver;
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work and I don't know why. The interceptor is never called.

Any ideas ?

Thank you

`edit` : here is the BasicInterceptor

```
    package org.resthub.dashboard;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
    import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

    public class BasicInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

        @Override
        public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
                ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);

            System.out.println("INTERCEPTORORRR§§§§§§");
            if (modelAndView != null && modelAndView.getModelMap() != null) {
    ...
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you verified that your configuration class is actually used?

Comment: yes and the function addInterceptors is well called.

Comment: Is there @Intercept used in BasicInterceptor class ?

Comment: What does your `BasicInterceptor` look like?

Comment: no I don't have this annotation. What version of Spring MVC do I need ? I can't find it.

Comment: The `addInterceptor()` method returns an [`InterceptorRegistration`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/InterceptorRegistration.html) that you can use to configure the registered interceptor. For example, you can add URL patterns it should apply to. If you configure a URL pattern to apply to the `Interceptor`, does that work?

Comment: I have added the class. It doesn't change with a pattern.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java config for spring interceptor where interceptor is using autowired spring beans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349180/java-config-for-spring-interceptor-where-interceptor-is-using-autowired-spring-b)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your configuration is correct, at least if you have verified that it is in fact picked up. However, what could be the problem is that something happens during the request that causes `postHandle` not to be executed. Make sure that no execption is thrown during request execution. And to verify that the Interceptor is in fact used, you can implement `preHandle` or `afterCompletion` and see if those methods are executed.

Comment: None of those functions is executed. Very strange.

Comment: In that case, are you sure that your controller is invoked at all? You're not trying to access a resource that is not handled by Spring MVC?

Comment: yes i'm sure because it works with the xml configuration of the interceptor.

Comment: well, im going to return to the xml config

Comment: Are you running any xml-config and annotation config simultaneously?

Comment: yes I have 2 xml. appContext and springSecurity. Except the interceptor in the appContext, I only have this <mongo:repositories base-package="org.resthub.dashboard.repository" /> but I don't know how to transform in the annotation format

Comment: Do you remember the fix by any chance? I have the same issue