# Java config for spring interceptor where interceptor is using autowired spring beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, interceptor

I want to add spring mvc interceptor as part of Java config. I already have a xml based config for this but I am trying to move to a Java config. For interceptors, I know that it can be done like this from the spring documentation-

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new LocaleInterceptor());
    }

}
```

But my interceptor is using a spring bean autowired into it like follows-

```
public class LocaleInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdaptor {

    @Autowired
    ISomeService someService;

    ...
}
```

The SomeService class looks like follows-

```
@Service
public class SomeService implements ISomeService {

   ...
}
```

I am using annotations like `@Service` for scanning the beans and have not specified them in the configuration class as `@Bean`

As my understanding, since java config uses new for creating the object, spring will not automatically inject the dependencies into it.

How can I add the interceptors like this as part of the java config?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Just do the following:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    LocaleInterceptor localInterceptor() {
         return new LocalInterceptor();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeInterceptor());
    }

}
```

Of course `LocaleInterceptor` needs to be configured as a Spring bean somewhere (XML, Java Config or using annotations) in order for the relevant field of `WebConfig` to get injected.

The documentation for general customization of Spring's MVC configuration can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config), and specifically for Interceptors see [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-interceptors) section

Comment: To get this to work in Spring 3.2.12, I had to add ```@Component``` to my equivalent of ```LocaleInterceptor```

Comment: @Nathan That is correct. If you are using classpath scanning to create a `LocaleInterceptor` that is a Spring Bean, then you naturally need the `@Component` annotation. Otherwise you could configure the Spring Bean in XML or Java Config

Comment: Any idea where in Spring's documentation (not JavaDoc) this is mentioned? This whole WebMvcConfigurerAdapter stuff.

Comment: @ecbrodie Good question! Check out my updated answer for the link!

Comment: Reason for downvote: This approach causes "Circular dependency injection problem" if you try to inject (Autowire) Spring repository beans inside Interceptor class and try to call JPAEntityManager

Answer (score 19):

When you handle the object creation for yourself like in:

```
registry.addInterceptor(new LocaleInterceptor());
```

there is no way the Spring container can manage that object for you and therefore make the necessary injection into your `LocaleInterceptor`.

Another way that could be more convenient for your situation, is to declare the managed `@Bean` in the `@Configuration` and use the method directly, like so:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public LocaleInterceptor localeInterceptor() {
        return new LocaleInterceptor();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor( localeInterceptor() );
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me in Spring 3.2.12 but the accepted answer didn't.

Comment: I can't see the difference between the two, asides from the fact this one at least explains the reason for the problem.

Comment: Not anymore, because it was edited after that @Haroldo_OK

Answer (score 14):

Try to inject your service as a constructor parameter. It is simple.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

   @Autowired
   ISomeService someService;

   @Override
   public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new LocaleInterceptor(someService));
   }

}
```

Then reconfigure your interceptor,

```
public class LocaleInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdaptor {


     private final ISomeService someService;

     public LocaleInterceptor(ISomeService someService) {
         this.someService = someService;
     }


}
```

Cheers !