# Spring Boot interceptor can not get autowired Environment?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

```
@Component
public class AuthorizeInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthorizeInterceptor.class);

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        log.info("env:",env);
        return true;
    }
}
```

env is `null`, some config use `@Value()` can not get value as well, always `null`
we add this interceptor `registry.addInterceptor(new Interceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**");` it is `new`!
one way to get value is `BeanFactory.getBean("beanname")`.
but how can i let spring manager this interceptor,so i can use `@Autowired`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349180/java-config-for-spring-interceptor-where-interceptor-is-using-autowired-spring-b

Answer (score 1):

It should be `log.info("env: {}", env);`

I believe you forgot to put the placeholder `{}` in you logger call.

Comment: usage of log is error, but the value is really `null`