# Application Properties value in Spring boot interceptor

Tags: spring, spring-boot, interceptor

Could anyone please help me to read the application properties values in Spring Boot interceptor (`preHandle` method)?

I am trying to write some logic in `preHandle`. This logic needs to get some values from `application.properties` file. I use `@Value` annotation but it is always null.

Thanks

Comment: how are you creating HandlerInterceptor, @Value should work on HandlerInterceptors. Could u post your code where you are creating HandlerInterceptor and @Value?

Comment: Are you sure that you have your properties file on classpath?

Comment: Are you trying to get value like this @Value("${yourValue.Key}")

Comment: Can you try with autowiring `Environment`  interface and use its object method-`getProperty("key")` to get value from `application.properties` file

Comment: hi @AjitSoman, Yes I tried. It didnt help me. BTW, I have solved and posted my here. Thanks

Comment: Hi @PraneethRamesh, Hmm.. may be. I posted the details below.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23349234/1165178

Answer (score 8):

I solved the problem. Here is the detail.

Before solution:

```
// Custom interceptor class
public class XYZCustomInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor{
@Value("${JWT.secret}")
private String jwtSecret;

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
                               response, Object arg2) throws Exception {

 // I am using the jwtSecret in this method for parsing the JWT
 // jwtSecret is NULL

  }
}


 //To Register (another class)

 @Configuration
 public class XYZWebappWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

 @Override
 public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry){

    registry.addInterceptor(new                         
                 XYZCustomWebappInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**");
   }

}
```

When the interceptor (XYZCustomWebappInterceptor) is added by creating a class using 'new' keyword, then Spring boot will not understand the annotations. Thats why when I read those values (jwtSecret from application.properties) in XYZCustomWebappInterceptor, it is null.

How I solved:

```
//Read those properties values in this class and pass it to interceptor's 
//constructor method. 

 @Configuration
 public class XYZWebappWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

 @Value("${JWT.secret}")
 private String jwtSecret;

 @Override
 public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry){

    registry.addInterceptor(new                         

    XYZCustomWebappInterceptor(jwtSecret)).addPathPatterns("/**");
   }

}


// Custom interceptor class
public class XYZCustomInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor{

private String jwtSecret;

RbsCustomWebappInterceptor(String secret){
    this.jwtSecret = secret;
}

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
                               response, Object arg2) throws Exception {


 // I am using the jwtSecret in this method for parsing the JWT
 // Now, jwtSecret is NOT NULL

  }
}
```

Thanks all for helping me.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest the following solution

```
   @Configuration
public class XYZWebappWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{



@Autowired
private XYZCustomWebappInterceptor xyzCustomWebappInterceptor;

 @Override
 public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry){

    registry.addInterceptor(xyzCustomWebappInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/**");
   }

}
```

In actual class you would do the following

```
// Custom interceptor class
@Component
public class XYZCustomInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor{
@Value("${JWT.secret}")
private String jwtSecret;

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
                           response, Object arg2) throws Exception {
//use the secret key
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For non-webmvc springboot application.

If your requirement is to read table name from property file then use below code snippet.

```
  @Slf4j
  @Component
  public class HibernateInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Value(value = "${user.documents.table.name}")
    private String targetTableName;
    
    private static String FINAL_TABLE_NAME;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        FINAL_TABLE_NAME = targetTableName;
    }
   
    @Override
    public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
          log.info("tagetTableName::"+FINAL_TABLE_NAME);
          //String prepedStatement = super.onPrepareStatement(sql);
          sql = sql.replaceAll("filenet_tfa_documents", FINAL_TABLE_NAME);
          //log.info("new table name:"+sql);
          return sql;
    }
    
}
```